# What is the noun to mean an act of the verb "to confer", as in, having discussions, exchange ideas/opinions?

Tags: nouns

I am looking to say that two people did not confer during the undertaking of a particular task, but my sentence structure requires a noun... "The two people undertook the task simultaneously without .....".

Conferring, conferral, confirment?

A google search did not lead me to 100% confidence of an answer on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: There's the word *conference*, which is certainly a noun form of *confer*, but it doesn't quite fit your sentence.

Comment: [Onelook](https://onelook.com/?w=confirment&ls=a) says that none of its dictionaries has an entry for "confirment". Why do you think that that may be a word?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just say *without conferring*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you insist on a noun you could use ***consultation***:

> the act of exchanging information and opinions about something in order to reach a better understanding of it or to make a decision, or a meeting for this purpose:
>
> - [ U ] We hope to work in ***consultation*** with Congress on how the law should be interpreted. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consultation))

However, a more idiomatic way of expressing this would be to use a gerund after *without* in your sentence:

> The two people undertook the task simultaneously without ***consulting*** *each other*.

Comment: Could use a further sense of agreeing, which *conferring* provides.